# Recursive Allocation of Sets by Criterion

Tags: python, recursion

So I'm trying to get my head around a recursive allocation problem.

Essentially, for each element from set A, I am trying to assign an element from set B, where |A| <= |B|. 

An element from B may only be assigned to one element from A and only if it meets the 'safe' criteria.

 Doing up a smaller version of this problem (with a much simpler safe check) in python yields the following, where f(A,B) returns the set of paired allocations given you have the set of B left to be assigned to set A

```
A = ["A0","A1","A2"]
B = ["B0","B1","B2","B3"]

def issafe(a,b):
    return int(a[1]) <= int(b[1])

def f(A,B):
    if A == []:
        return []
    else:
        for i in range(len(B)):
            if issafe(A[0],B[i]):
                 return [(A[0],B[i])] + f(A[1:],B[0:i]+B[i+1:])
```

So running the function with the initial sets,

```
f(A,B)
=> [('A0', 'B0'), ('A1', 'B1'), ('A2', 'B2')]
```

Which is a safe allocation from of b's to a's. However is only one possible safe allocation.

 I was hoping someone could give me some guidance on how to expand this solution such that it gives all the safe allocations.

 So something like

```
f(A,B)
=> [[('A0', 'B0'), ('A1', 'B1'), ('A2', 'B2')],
    [('A0', 'B1'), ('A1', 'B2'), ('A2', 'B3')],
    [                  ...                   ]]
```

---

Making changes as per Prune's comments:

```
def f(A,B):
    C = []
    if A == []:
        return []
    else:
        for i in range(len(B)):
            if issafe(A[0],B[i]):
                C.append([(A[0],B[i])] + f(A[1:],B[0:i]+B[i+1:]))
    return C
```

This gives output of a tree structure:

```
[
[('A0', 'B0'),[('A1', 'B1'), [('A2', 'B2')], [('A2', 'B3')]], [('A1', 'B2'), [('A2', 'B3')]], [('A1', 'B3'), [('A2', 'B2')]]], 
[('A0', 'B1'), [('A1', 'B2'), [('A2', 'B3')]], [('A1', 'B3'), [('A2', 'B2')]]], 
[('A0', 'B2'), [('A1', 'B1'), [('A2', 'B3')]], [('A1', 'B3')]], 
[('A0', 'B3'), [('A1', 'B1'), [('A2', 'B2')]], [('A1', 'B2')]]
]
```

Which I believe is correct, but I'm still not sure if there is a method which will yield the sets of safe allocations themselves as apposed to a tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was added an input into the function to store what had been allocated so far and one input to store the saved solns. Then when I reached the end condition, I stored the allocated pairs into the soln, in other words

```
def f(A,B,Assigned = [],Soln = []):
C = []
#If we've assigned all A's
if A == []:
  #Add this assignment list to soln list
  Soln.append(Assigned)
  #Return blank to stop recursion
  return ([],Soln)
else:
    for i in range(len(B)):
      #For unassigned safe B's
        if issafe(A[0],B[i]):
            C.append(   [(A[0],B[i])]               #Newly assigned pair
                      + [f(A[1:], B[0:i] + B[i+1:], #Remainder to be assigned
                         Assigned + [(A[0],B[i])],  #Update assigned list
                         Soln)[0]])                 #'Transfer' soln to next itteration 
return (C,Soln)

Ans = f(AInit,BInit)[1]

for a in Ans:
  print (a)
```

This yielded the solution I was after, and as far as I am aware, would work for any set of A's and B's and various safe confitions

```
[('A0', 'B0'), ('A1', 'B1'), ('A2', 'B2')]
[('A0', 'B0'), ('A1', 'B1'), ('A2', 'B3')]
[('A0', 'B0'), ('A1', 'B2'), ('A2', 'B3')]
[('A0', 'B0'), ('A1', 'B3'), ('A2', 'B2')]
[('A0', 'B1'), ('A1', 'B2'), ('A2', 'B3')]
[('A0', 'B1'), ('A1', 'B3'), ('A2', 'B2')]
[('A0', 'B2'), ('A1', 'B1'), ('A2', 'B3')]
[('A0', 'B3'), ('A1', 'B1'), ('A2', 'B2')]
```

Thanks to Prune for your help and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach is recursive.  On a given call:

- Base case:
  If either A or B is empty, you're done; return.
- Recursion case:

  - For the first element of A, try each element of B in turn (i.e. a **for** loop).  If that pairing is legal, then recur on the remaining list.
  - Concatenate / append all of the successful allocations and return that to the next level up.

Does that move you toward a solution?

Comment: It is that last dot point that I am having trouble with, as the rest of what you have said I agree with and understand completely. Does that mean my function needs to have an additional input to which I am appending the completed list? And if so how does that not mess up calling the function within the recursion

Comment: You append the results in your **for** loop, and then **return** that list as the functional result.

Comment: Making changes as per your comments, gives a 'tree structure' (I've posted changes in the question). This could be reformatted to give all the solutions outside of the function, but I just wanted to check that this is what you meant or if there is something I'm still missing.

Comment: That the idea!  Now, you need to handle your reconstruction a bit better, so you have a list of solutions, instead of a tree structure.  Iterate through the returned solutions, and append *each* solution individually to the lead pair.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that this will be dominated by list creation and concatenation very quickly.  An iterator would be a good way to deal with this, e.g.:

```
def allsafe(x, y):
      if not x:
          yield ()
      else:
          v_x = x[0]
          remaining = x[1:]
          for i, v_y in enumerate(y):
              if not issafe(v_x, v_y):
                  continue
              point = (v_y, )
              if remaining:
                  for solution in allsafe(remaining, y[:i]):
                      yield point + solution
                  for solution in allsafe(remaining, y[i+1:]):
                      yield point + solution
              else:
                  yield point

def test():
    a = ["A%d" % i for i in xrange(6)]
    b = ["B%d" % i for i in xrange(30)]
    for b_solution in allsafe(a, b):
        # Don't print with large a/b sizes if you value your terminal history
        print 'solution: %s' % zip(a, list(b_solution))
```

Note that I used tuples and a zip, but they don't matter much.  This runs ~15x faster for the given sizes (`|A|=6`, `|B|=30`), ~20x faster for 6, 32, ~25x faster for 6, 35, etc.